# Selected tab wont show contet inside it

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu bar on the top left for selecting list, and the navigation which display what was selected from menu bar. Selected item from menu bar must be active on the menu bar and navigation bar which is working fine. The only problem is the contents inside the selected item is not displayed. I m using jquery and bootstrap to achieve this.

**What I get** 
[image: The results I get]

**What I want to achieve**
[image: The layout of what I want to achieve.]

My code is also available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/JayStar/9y1wsr60/)

```js
  $("#learnBootstrap").click(function(){
  debugger;
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  console.log("Learn Bootstrap Active");
  });
  $("#learnHTML").click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  console.log("Learn HTML Active");
  });
  $("#learnCSS").click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  console.log("Learn CSS Active");
  });
  $("#learnJavaScript").click(function() {
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  console.log("Learn JavaScript Active");
  });
  $("#learnjQuery").click(function() {
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  console.log("Learn jQuery Active");
  });
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="margin-left: -2%">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left"> 
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
  data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
  aria-expanded="false">Todo List<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">      
       <li><a href="#learnBootstrap" data-toggle="tab">Learn Bootstrap</a></li>
       <li><a href="#learnHTML" data-toggle="tab">Learn HTML</a></li
       <li><a href="#learnCSS" data-toggle="tab">Learn CSS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#learnJavaScript" data-toggle="tab">Learn JavaScript</a></li>
       <li><a href="#learnjQuery" data-toggle="tab">Learn jQuery</a></li>       
      </ul>
    </li>    
   </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
   <div class="panel-body">
      <div><h2>List</h2></div>
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">       
    <li id="learnBootstrap"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Learn Bootstrap</a>      </li>
 <li id="learnHTML"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Learn HTML</a></li>
 <li id="learnCSS"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Learn CSS</a></li>
 <li id="learnJavaScript"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Learn JavaScript</a></li>
 <li id="learnjQuery"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Learn jQuery</a></li>       
</ul>
    <div class="tab-content">        
     <div class="tab-pane home" id="learnBootstrap">
         <h3>Learn Bootstrap goes here</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="learnHTML">
      <h3>Learn HTML content goes here</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="learnCSS">
      <h3>Learn CSS content goes here</h3>
     </div>   
     <div class="tab-pane" id="learnJavaScript">
         <h3>Learn JavaScript content goes here</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="learnjQuery">
      <h3>Learn jQuery content goes here</h3>
     </div>
      
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//----- Bootstrap Portion

$("#learnBootstraplink").click(function(){
$('.nav-tabs li').removeClass('active');
$('.bootstrap').addClass('active');
$('.tab-pane').removeClass('in active');
$('.tab-content div#learnBootstrap').addClass('in active');
console.log("Learn Bootstrap Active");
});
//------ HTML Portion

$("#learnHTMLlink").click(function(){
$('.nav-tabs li').removeClass('active');
$('.html').addClass('active');
$('.tab-pane').removeClass('in active');
$('.tab-content div#learnHTML').addClass('in active');
console.log("Learn HTML Active");
});
//------ CSS Portion

$("#learnCSSlink").click(function(){
$('.nav-tabs li').removeClass('active');
$('.css').addClass('active');
$('.tab-pane').removeClass('in active');
$('.tab-content div#learnCSS').addClass('in active');
console.log("Learn css Active");
});
//------- JS Portion

$("#learnJavaScriptlink").click(function(){
$('.nav-tabs li').removeClass('active');
$('.js').addClass('active');
$('.tab-pane').removeClass('in active');
$('.tab-content div#learnJavascript').addClass('in active');
console.log("Learn js Active");
});
//------- JQUERY Portion

$("#learnjQuerylink").click(function(){
$('.nav-tabs li').removeClass('active');
$('.jquery').addClass('active');
$('.tab-pane').removeClass('in active');
$('.tab-content div#learnJQuery').addClass('in active');
console.log("Learn jquery Active");
});
```

You have to add attribute id in todo list items for having click functionality and add classes in the list items of nav-tab list for identifying.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left"> 
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
    data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
    aria-expanded="false">Todo List<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">                      
            <li><a id="learnBootstraplink" href="#learnBootstrap" data-toggle="tab">Learn Bootstrap</a></li>
            <li><a id="learnHTMLlink" href="#learnHTML" data-toggle="tab">Learn HTML</a></li>
            <li><a id="learnCSSlink" href="#learnCSS" data-toggle="tab">Learn CSS</a></li>
            <li><a id="learnJavaScriptlink" href="#learnJavascript" data-toggle="tab">Learn JavaScript</a></li>
            <li><a id="learnjQuerylink" href="#learnJQuery" data-toggle="tab">Learn jQuery</a></li>                         
        </ul>
    </li>               
</ul>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="bootstrap active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#learnBootstrap">Bootstrap</a></li>
    <li class="html"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#learnHTML">HTML</a></li>
    <li class="css"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#learnCSS">CSS</a></li>
    <li class="js"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#learnJavascript">JS</a></li>
     <li class="jquery"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#learnJQuery">Jquery</a></li>
  </ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="learnBootstrap" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Bootstrap</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="learnHTML" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>HTMl</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="learnCSS" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>CSS</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="learnJavascript" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>JS</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="learnJQuery" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Jquery</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the working example [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sikandar_ali_akram/8kb68ofx/3/)

Comment: @Sikandar_li I know the part you did works well.  Did you see the **small menu bar** at the top left corner. Above the navigation.